# Why can I not load/find the main class?

Tags: java, class

Basically I get the error message: "Error: Could not find or load main class Driver" Why Am I getting this error? This is my first instance working with classes, so I am unsure of my syntax in my code. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
public class Person {
private String name;//a variable that contains a person's name
private int age;//a variable that contain's a person's age

public class Driver{
    public void main(String[] args )
    {
        String name1="John";
        int age1=30;
        Person person1= new Person();
        person1.setName(name1);
        person1.setAge(age1);
        System.out.print(person1.getName());
        System.out.print(person1.getAge());
    }
}
//returns the age of a person
public int getAge(){
    return age;
}

//returns the name of a person
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

//changes name of a person
public void setName(String s)
{
    name=s;
}

//changes age of a person
public void setAge(int x)
{
    age=x;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

The JVM can't locate the `main` method as specified by the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

> The method main must be declared public, **static**, and void.

You need to make the inner class a top level class and make the `main` method `static` (since static methods can only belong to top level classes)

```
public class Driver {
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`public void main(String[] args )` should be `public static void main(String[] args )`

Comment: Ah, but if I do that I receive an error message of "The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type". That was my original code but I changed it because eclipse gave me this.

Comment: + there seems to be multiple to-level classes in one file, which is invalid.

Comment: @user2453836 Because you have to put the main method in the top level class, i.e the class `Person`.

Comment: @user2453836 what is the purpose of Driver class? If only to hold `main` method then just move this method to other top-level class like `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make inner class `static` as well as `main` method. You can't put `static` method on instance inner class.

```
public class Person {
 public static class Driver{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ....
    }
 }
}
```